# How to reset grub to see both windows 7 and ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: boot

After reinstalling windows 7 on my computer I receive the follow error on bootup

```
bootmgr error
```

I can only boot into windows if I unplug the linux hard drive and I can only boot into Linux if I press <kbd>Esc</kbd> to open the BIOS and select the linux hard drive.

I tried using

```
update grub-install
```

but that did not seem to help. How do I get grub back to its original self with both OSs to boot into from the grub menu?

Below is my sudo update-grub command:

```
$ sudo update-grub
[sudo] password for gin: 
Generating grub.cfg ...
Warning: Setting GRUB_TIMEOUT to a non-zero value when GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT is set is no longer supported.
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.8.0-39-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.8.0-39-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.8.0-37-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.8.0-37-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.8.0-36-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.8.0-36-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.8.0-35-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.8.0-35-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.8.0-34-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.8.0-34-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.8.0-29-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.8.0-29-generic
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.bin
done
```

Below is my fdisk command

```
$ sudo fdisk -l
[sudo] password for gin: 

Disk /dev/sda: 120.0 GB, 120000000000 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 14589 cylinders, total 234375000 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x000764a1

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048   226250751   113124352   83  Linux
/dev/sda2       226252798   234373119     4060161    5  Extended
/dev/sda5       226252800   234373119     4060160   82  Linux swap / Solaris

WARNING: GPT (GUID Partition Table) detected on '/dev/sdb'! The util fdisk doesn't support GPT. Use GNU Parted.


Disk /dev/sdb: 1000.2 GB, 1000204886016 bytes
256 heads, 63 sectors/track, 121126 cylinders, total 1953525168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x8d19c4c4

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1               1  4294967295  2147483647+  ee  GPT
Partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary.

Disk /dev/sdg: 4009 MB, 4009754624 bytes
145 heads, 48 sectors/track, 1125 cylinders, total 7831552 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x0004e24a

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdg1   *          48     7831551     3915752    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT

Disk /dev/mapper/cryptswap1: 4157 MB, 4157603840 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 505 cylinders, total 8120320 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x45a3a931

Disk /dev/mapper/cryptswap1 doesn't contain a valid partition table
```

My first attempt at [How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows)

```
$ sudo mount /dev/sda /mnt
mount: /dev/sda already mounted or /mnt busy
gin@ger:~$ for i in /sys /proc /run /dev; do sudo mount --bind "$i" "/mnt$i"; done
mount: mount point /mnt/sys does not exist
mount: mount point /mnt/proc does not exist
mount: mount point /mnt/run does not exist
mount: mount point /mnt/dev does not exist
gin@ger:~$ sudo chroot /mnt
chroot: failed to run command `/bin/bash': No such file or directory
```

Below is my boot order:

```
UEFI BOOT SOURCES
    WINDOWS BOOT MANAGER
LEGACY BOOT SOURCES
    HARD DRIVE
        SATO0
        SATO1
NETWORK CONTROLLER (REALTEK PXE B07 D00)
```

Comment: How did you install Ubuntu?  Replace the word LiveCD with whatever that method is...

Comment: Is /dev/sda internal or external?

Comment: You ran the wrong command. You want `sudo update-grub` not `update grub-install`.

Comment: OK then follow the steps outlined in the other post using /dev/sda as the grub install location as @terdon suggests

Comment: Correct... You took the right approach in separating the drives like you did.  If you want GRUB2 to be able to boot Windows 7, make sure os-prober is installed.  IIRC it is by default.

Comment: You must boot from the live CD and determine the proper disk using fdisk -l

Comment: How do i boot from the live CD?

Comment: Does boot from a live CD mean that I have reinstall linux again on its disk drive?

Comment: no follow the post, try `sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt`

Comment: I tried the post solution, and I posted my results above these comments. Did I do something wrong?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14562/discussion-between-e-carter-young-and-linuxfreebird)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. **Do not unplug** hard drive which is Windows system on, either the hard drive installed ubuntu.
2. **Change the order of hard drive in bios, set the hard drive which installed ubuntu on top of the list, keep the Ubuntu can startup as default.**
3. Boot, and login to Ubuntu
4. run **update-grub** in terminal as root. you will find something in terminal, like:

   "Found Windows 7 (loader) on /dev/sdxX"

sucess!

1. you can change the boot order by edit `/etc/default/grub`. change the `GRUB_DEFAULT=0` to whatever you want. (0: means the first item in grub menu; 1: means the second item in grub menu. You can find grub menu by press 'shift' or down arrow key while you boot your system, or check `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` in ubuntu)

good luck!

Comment: I posted my current boot order. SATO0 is ubunut. I think SATO1 is windows. I think the windows boot manager is causing the problem. Not sure how to move it or remove it in the boot order.

Comment: My attempt at implementing your answer did not work. Is the window manager interfering somehow?

Comment: Can Ubuntu boot up successfully without any operations ? Or Which one can boot up successfully?

Comment: Is your Windows 7 installed in EFI mode and Ubuntu installed in Legacy/MBR mode? If it is ture, you need convert Ubuntu into EFI mode. Ubuntu must be installed as the same as Windows does, and ubuntu/grub2 will boot windows in correct way. Just keep in mind, this convertion do not need to reinstall Windows and Ubuntu. You can look [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI) and [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing) to find what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Connect your external hard disk boot into Ubuntu, mount your Windows 7 partition and try running this in terminal

> sudo update-grub

For mounting you no need to use terminal just open windows 7 partition in nautilus.